Use of 頂く possibly not involving speaker
In Persona 3, a character states that the player would make a good detective. They then say:

まずは、ベレー帽とパイプをお求め頂くことをお勧めします

At first, I thought the beneficiary of 頂く would be the speaker, but that seemed strange as that would mean they're essentially recommending that they receive something from the listener.
If not that though, does it mean that 頂く can be used for situations that don't involve the speaker, like with もらう, and that this line explicitly implies someone else will be purchasing the items for the listener? That also seems a bit off, but I assume お求めになる would be used instead if they wanted to simply recommend the listener buys something themself.

Isn't it just a humble recommendation?

My hangup is with the fact that adding 頂く would make the speaker the focus of the action, which makes it almost come across as self-directed, as in "I recommend that I get you to buy this". I'm willing to accept it as kiego for the sake of keigo, but surely it'd sound strange if exchanged for the functionally synonymous もらう, right?

The "receiver" is not necessarily the speaker but someone who the speaker empathizes with, which is the case in this sentence.

One of the meanings of もらう is simply "to get", see entry number 2) in the following link: https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/%E8%B2%B0%E3%81%86/#jn-220352

That meaning of simply "getting" is available for もらう as a standalone verb, but I was under the impression that as auxiliary verbs, like in this case, both it and 頂く explicitly imply another party does the attached verb. Just to be clear, are you saying that the speaker in this situation is saying that the addressee should receive the act of 求める from someone else?

In your case it is not 〜て頂く, but rather お連用形頂く. It is just humble speech.

Who is the speaker? If the speaker is associated with selling such items in some way, the speaker might benefit, if indirectly.
